# How to stop IntelliJ removing indentation from chained method calls?

Tags: intellij-idea, indentation, code-formatting

I want to keep manual indentation in *some* chained method calls using IntelliJ IDEA, so that the `given`, `when`, `then` are all not indented, but the formatter keeps shifting it back.

I type:

```scala
    given
      .spec(withAcceptsGzipHeader)
      .authenticatedAsStandardUser()
    .when
      .get(resourceUnderTestPath)
    .Then()
      .statusCode(OK)
      .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_ENCODING, "gzip")
      .body("", hasKey(LICENCE_ID_OPTION))
```

and the formatter changes it to:

```scala
    given
      .spec(withAcceptsGzipHeader)
      .authenticatedAsStandardUser()
      .when
      .get(resourceUnderTestPath)
      .Then()
      .statusCode(OK)
      .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_ENCODING, "gzip")
      .body("", hasKey(LICENCE_ID_OPTION))
```

- I have *Wrapping and Braces* -> *Chained method calls* -> *Align when muiltiline* unchecked.
- I know about `@formatter:off/on` but that's not quite a proper solution.

[This post](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000233830-Continuation-indent-in-conditional-statements-and-chained-method-calls?flash_digest=1a9fb9161755d15f57f2c75419841145f665cfaa) seems to ask for what I need. Surprised this hasn't been solved yet!